# How to notify the programmer of which function overload is run?

Tags: c++, gcc, overloading

Basically, I'm looking for a way to print a message at run-time (or maybe at compile-time) to notify me of which function overload the compiler selected.

An example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>


void removeDuplicateChars( const std::string& str );
void removeDuplicateChars( std::string_view&& strView );


int main( )
{
    std::cout << "Enter the string: ";
    std::string str;
    std::cin >> str;
    removeDuplicateChars( str ); // here it should give a message like "string overload"

    std::cout << '\n';

    removeDuplicateChars( std::string_view( "1235328" ) ); // and here it should give a message
                                                           // like "string_view overload"

    return 0;
}
```

I have to mention that I simply can't print out these messages inside the body of each function cause these are recursive functions and that would mean the message would be printed multiple times!

So is there a simple way to do this? I don't want to objdump and check the object file.

Comment: Implement two more overloads called `log_and_call_removeDuplicateChars` that are defined the same way, call them instead everywhere in the code, and have them log which one gets called, before they call the real function?

Comment: Well you could run your program in a debugger, single step through it and see what function is used. At compile time you could put a static_assert(false,"message") to find it out.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik Interesting. So these two helper functions will have to log and then call the two real functions?

Comment: @Pepijn Kramer Oh I had thought about taking advantage of `static_assert` but I couldn't find a proper way to do it. Thanks. BTW, should I keep the condition as *false* until I finally decide to disable the message?

Comment: Isn't that what I wrote?

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik I guess it is. I just wanted to make sure.

Comment: Yes the static assert is just there to check it once. By keeping it false your build will fail, but at least you will get a message